# Set player score with playerprefs

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to save a players score to display it as highscore and keep it each time the game either is restarted or the scene is restarted. I have the following:

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

public static int score = 0;
static int highScore = 0;
public Text text;

public static void AddPoint(){
    score++;
    if (score > highScore) {
        highScore = score;
    }
}

void Start(){
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();
    score = 0;
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highScore", 0);
}

void onDestroy(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highScore", highScore);
}

void Update () {
    text.text = "Score: " + score + "\nHigh Score: " + highScore;
}
}
```

This causes my score and highscore to be incremented each time I hit a trigger to gain a point. However I then use a trigger to say if I hit an object to restart the scene.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        print ("You collided!");
        collided = true;
        rb.gravityScale = 10;
        rb.drag = 0;
        Invoke("startOver", 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Once the scene is restarted both variables highScore and score are being reset back to zero. I am guessing because my game is not saving the highScore. How can I save the score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` before your game restarts

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        print ("You collided!");
        collided = true;
        rb.gravityScale = 10;
        rb.drag = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highScore", highScore);
        Invoke("startOver", 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work but I also found out why it wasn't saving. I'm such a dummy. I had onDestroy() instead of OnDestroy()